# Scala.js cross-project wrong dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, sbt-assembly

In my `build.sbt` I have a cross-project (js + jvm), and I depend on the jvm part in my other project (let’s call it `events`). Here’s the part of my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val common = (crossProject in file(“common”)).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
lazy val common_js = common.js
lazy val common_jvm = common.jvm
lazy val events = (project in file (“events)).dependsOn(common_jvm)
```

But this setup fails when I do `sbt events/assembly`. The error is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
JS_DEPENDENCIES
/Users/riakovle/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-library_2.11/0.6.13/scalajs-library_2.11-0.6.13.jar:JS_DEPENDENCIES
```

If I do the `dependencyGraph`, I see my `events` project depends on `common:common_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT`, and the aforementioned `scalajs-library` comes transitively from it.
So it seems my common js dependency creeps in somehow, even though I haven't specified it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more information on events?  Is it a custom library you have built and properly setup for use on js/jvm? I am unclear.  It sounds like your attempting to share code between js/jvm sub projects but compilation is having issues.

Comment: Uh, oh. This seems to be an incompatibility between `assembly` and how Scala.js manages JS dependencies internally...

Comment: This question was answered on Gitter: https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js?at=5829e718df5ae9664556da57, and I've updated the code to include the problematic piece. I'll let the author of the answer to post it here and get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably specifying the `ScalaJSPlugin` on the JVM project, either directly or via `crossProject`. The plugin is only needed when creating a regular SBT project, as `crossProject` includes it automatically for the JS subproject.

Comment: Thanks, your assumption is correct. I've updated the code in the question to include the problematic part. I've enabled the `ScalaJSPlugin` on the cross-project, and this has led to the described behavior. After removing it all is good.